# Robust Linear Regression Results in Python and Stata Do Not Agree

Tags: python, statistics, regression, stata, statsmodels

My groupmates and I were doing this assignment that involves running a regression on Fama-French 3 factor model. I used python Statsmodels module and they used Stata and we share the same set of data. For Ordinary Least Squares regression, we got the same answers. But robust regression results for some reason don't agree.

Here is the result from Stata:
[image]

Here is the result from Statsmodels:
[image]

Just wondering what could be the cause of this issue? Any way to resolve it? I also tried different methods (HuberT, RamsayE etc) in Statsmodels and none of them had the same answers as the result from Stata. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can comment on what you did it in Stata. `regress, robust` is robust in one specific sense only: the standard errors are Huber-White-sandwich standard errors (yet another names exist). Otherwise the coefficients are exactly as OLS yields, as omitting the `robust` option will show you. I have no experience with Statsmodels, but it is not even trying to do the same thing. You are not the first person to be confused by the lack of consistency on what is meant by robust; at the same time Stata documentation goes into considerable detail on what it is doing.

Comment: Ironically, the good news here is that you don't really seem to need any fancy robust regression. Even the very different Huber-type robust method seems to end with a similar result. (The occurrence of Huber's name under both headings is fortuitous here and doesn't make the procedures even similar.)

Comment: In general posting screenshots as images is not so helpful as copying and pasting text into the forum software.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The equivalent of Stata's

`regress ..., robust`

in statsmodels is

`OLS(...).fit(cov_type='HC1')`

The options for the robust sandwich covariance matrices are here http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.get_robustcov_results.html, but the use is through the fit keywords.

There is an incomplete FAQ answer for differences in robust standard errors between Stata and statsmodels. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/1923

statsmodel.robust and RLM refer to outlier robust estimation. This is an M-estimator and the covariance has the original Huber sandwich form.

Here is the main page for statsmodels.robust
http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/rlm.html
and the documentation for RLM
http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.robust.robust_linear_model.RLM.html

Comment: @Nick Cox, that's not what I meant. The covariance of the parameters for M-estimators is of the sandwich form, that's where, AFAIU, Huber gets into Godambe/Eicker/Huber/White et al robust covariance matrices. (However, the RLM sandwich covariance is not heteroscedasticity consistent in terms of White, AFAIR.) The outlier part is not directly related to this, it is just an estimator where the information matrix equality doesn't hold.